# Why changing #cgo LDFLAGS -l cannot change the imported library

Tags: cgo

`#cgo LDFLAGS: -lmarket_n`
changed to
`#cgo LDFLAGS: -lmarket_m`

Then
`go clean -cache -r`

`go build -o newm`

Check what shared library the binary `newm` calls

`ldd newm`

Ironically, it reports

```
libmarket_n.so => not found
...
```

I have also renamed `libmarket_n.so` to `libmarket_m.so`,
Why did it keep on referring back to the old library name whose file no longer exists?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs at renaming `libmarket_n.so` to `libmarket_m.so`

This action Did Not change the library `market_n` to library `market_m` because its real name `market_n` is imprinted in its compiling process. And `go build` found out it really refers to the old name and finish the compiling to `newm`.

However, `ldd` analyzed `newm` and found it refers to the old library name which does not have a corresponding filename in the library path.

Thus either stick to its original name or recompile the library with the target name `market_m` and produce a real Linux shared object (so) `market_m`.